# 0 filesize when using move_uploaded_file()

Tags: file-upload, nginx, fastcgi, php

Permissions are in line (777, owned by NGINX, etc),
Folder is writable,
File is small,
Everything I've found on Google for the last 4 hours is correct / NA

Players are NGINX, PHP-FPM, FastCGI..

I upload the file, use move_uploaded_file to move to uploads directory and the file saves. However the file, upon inspection, is 0kb and 0px by 0px. EMPTY.

Not finding this issue anywhere online?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: FOUND IT.. The mounted drive was out of space. Errors said nothing about it until I started trying alternate move methods. move_uploaded_file and copy both don't report on space. rename() said device was full.. thar she be.. No space issues were showing because it's a second mounted drive.

Comment: @RyanThompson Great news, glad you found the problem.

Comment: computers! can be such espovti57qewty3c7p3ct4g o8

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes across this and everything seems to be perfect.. CHECK your disk space! In my case I was using a mounted drive so I didn't get any typical low-space errors.

move_uploaded_file and copy do NOT display space issues. I had to use rename() to get any useful details.

Hope this helps some poor soul.

Comment: dh -f if by the way is drive usage

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a similar issue as yours here - http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/1002-move_uploaded_file-corrupts-some-files

It seems the issue resides in transferring a GIF from a Windows machine to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try using copy function instead. `copy([source]),[destination]`. If this works, that means you have a permission issue with upload temp directory.

Have you checked the permission on upload temp directory? You can find the directive/path on php.ini file(upload_tmp_dir).

Comment: [Read the OP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863394/crazy-move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move-issue#comment27836013_18863394)